# circular reference excel formula makes VBA method return 0

Tags: excel, vba

I writing a VBA plug in function to perform rectangular rounding of a series.  In my VBA method I'd like to detect if there are empty cells above the cell containing the formula/VBA method. But, if I use ActiveCell in my method Excel complains of circular references and returns 0 instead of the return value of my method. Example method:

```
Function MovingAverageSmooth(r As Range, m As Integer)
    ' returns a smoothed average using the 'rectangular' method
    Dim cStart As Long, x As Long, total As Double, activeColumn As Long
    Dim vc As Long, vr As Long, count As Double, beforeCount As Long, afterCount As Long

    vc = r.Column
    vr = r.Row

    rStart = Max(1, vr - m)
    currentValue = Cells(vr, vc).Value
    activeColumn = ActiveCell.Column
    For x = rStart To vr + m
        If Application.IsNumber(Cells(x, vc).Value) Then
            total = total + Cells(x, vc).Value
            count = count + 1
            If Application.IsNumber(Cells(x, activeColumn).Value) Then
                If x < vr Then
                    beforeCount = beforeCount + 1
                End If
                If x > vr Then
                    afterCount = afterCount + 1
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    MovingAverageSmooth = total / count
    If afterCount = 0 Or beforeCount = 0 Or count = 0 Then
        MovingAverageSmooth = currentValue
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: How will the formula know what the ActiveCell is when it's calculating?  It seems like that could cause issues.

Comment: What @DougGlancy said is probably your problem (as well as the ActiveColumn reference). That being said, this is really hard code to understand since 1) you don't have comments and 2) your variable names don't have a whole lot of meaning.

Comment: So how do I know what cell is the formula in when my method is called?

Comment: r = row, vc = value column, vr = value row.  Seems clear enough.

Comment: To get the cell it's being called from, use Application.Caller.

Comment: would you mind adding your default test scenario to your question? like: C4=MocingAverageSmooth(X1:Y4,1) and the Data in X1:Y4? This would help to work on the same page with you.

Comment: You might want to edit your code too, as there is no definition of currentValue and I think it is eigther rStart or cStart. You do use Option Explicit, do you?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for you.  As mentioned in my comment, Application.Caller returns the cell that called the function:

```
Function MovingAverageSmooth(r As Range, m As Integer)
    ' returns a smoothed average using the 'rectangular' method
    Dim cStart As Long, x As Long, total As Double, activeColumn As Long
    Dim vc As Long, vr As Long, count As Double, beforeCount As Long, afterCount As Long

    vc = r.Column
    vr = r.Row

    rStart = Max(1, vr - m)
    currentValue = Cells(vr, vc).Value
    activeColumn = Application.Caller.Column
    For x = rStart To vr + m
        If Application.IsNumber(Cells(x, vc).Value) Then
            total = total + Cells(x, vc).Value
            count = count + 1
            If Application.IsNumber(Cells(x, activeColumn).Value) Then
                If x < vr Then
                    beforeCount = beforeCount + 1
                End If
                If x > vr Then
                    afterCount = afterCount + 1
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    MovingAverageSmooth = total / count
    If afterCount = 0 Or beforeCount = 0 Or count = 0 Then
        MovingAverageSmooth = currentValue
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: This will work, but has one significan downside:  while `Caller` allows access to cells other than those passed into the function, changes to those cells will _not_ trigger a recalculation.  In general it is better to pass into the function parameters that reference all relevant ranges.

Comment: That did not fix the circular reference issue.  It seems the Application.IsNumber(Cells(x, activeColumn).Value) method causes the issue.  I'm giving up on this approach until I learn more.